# Where can I find EEG database for autism-spectrum disorder patients?

Tags: medical, research

I want to do some research about autism-spectrum disorder with electroencephalography (EEG). For that, I am badly in need of EEG data from autism patients.

Where can I find such data?

Comment: Kindly I need EEG-dataset for autistic children

Answer (score 4):

You can request access to SFARI, which has some ASD patients with EEG data.
[SFARI Base](https://www.sfari.org/resource/sfari-base/)

You can also request access to ACE.

> [ACE](http://ace.loni.usc.edu/data/) will analyze four key forms of data:
>       •   EEG Data
>       •   Neuroanatomical Data
>       •   Genetics Data
>       •   Behavior Data

I saw a [reference](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/pipermail/eeglablist/2016/011364.html) indicating about 50 ASD patients are in the Australian EEG Database.

> The Australian EEG Database (AED) is a large, secure, web-based, searchable extendable database with viewing, export and analysis features. The de-identified dataset, resulting from an 11 year study at a regional public hospital, includes 18,500 EEG images, demographic data, clinical history, technician's notes and the neurologist's report for each patient.
>
> Researchers should apply via the primary contact (aed@newcastle.edu.au) for the release of data.

Here’s a [list of publicly available EEG datasets](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/~arno/fam2data/publicly_available_EEG_data.html). I’m not sure if any have autism patients, but it may be worth looking at if the ones above are not enough.